# The equivalence relation 'homeomorphism' includes which of the following partition of $A$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $ P= (0,1), Q= [0,1), U=(0,1], S= [0,1] $ and $T= \mathbb{R}$ and $A= \{P,Q,U,S,T\}.$ The equivalence relation 'homeomorphism' includes which of the following partition of $A$?

1. $\{ P, Q, U,S\},\{T\}$
2. $\{P,T\}, \{Q,U\}, \{S\}$
3. $\{P,T\}, \{Q\},\{U\}, \{S\}$

I know that $(0,1)$ is homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and $ [0,1) $ is homemorphic to $(0,1]$ . So is option $2$ correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, option 2 is correct for the reasons you stated. If you want a full proof you have to exclude 1 (3 is ruled out by $Q \simeq U$ (by $x \to 1-x$ e.g.), so they're not different classes), so show $P \not \simeq Q$ e.g. This is not so hard, as $Q$ has one point whose removal leaves the remainder connected (namely $0$) while $(0,1)$ or $\Bbb R$ (indeed homeomorphic) has no such point.